# Como Mostrar as posições (índices) do maior valor do meu array? se o valor se repetir escrever o índice onde o valor se repete também

Tags: java, java-8

eu consegui fazer com que o programa mostrasse o ultimo índice que possui o maior valor, mas o que eu quero é que ele me mostre todos os índices caso o maior valor venha a se repetir. Por exemplo: (3, 2, 3,3) teria que me retornar a posição 0 e 2. A saída teria que ser a seguinte: System.out.println("O maior numero está nas posições " + 0,2 e 3); caso tenha mais de dois números iguais tenho que acrescentar o 'e' no final.
No código atual cada vez que ele encontra um valor igual ao maior ele imprime em uma nova linha, gostaria que fosse impresso tudo na mesma frase usando ',' e 'e' em caso de mais de dois valores iguais.
Se alguém pudesse me ajudar ficaria agradecido.

```
public class arrayMaior
```

{
public static void main(String[] args){

```
int maiorNumero= 0;
int numero[] = new int[5];
int posicao[] = new int[5] ;

for(int i =0; i<numero.length; i++){
  numero[i] = Entrada.leiaInt("Digite um numero");
  if(numero[i] >= maiorNumero){          
    maiorNumero =  numero[i];
  }       
}
for(int e = 0; e<numero.length; e++){
  if(numero[e] == maiorNumero){
    System.out.println("o maior numero está na posição " + e);        
  }     
}  

System.out.println("O maior numero é " + maiorNumero );
```

}
}

Comment: `posicao` também precisa ser um vetor; aí você adiciona a ele sempre que entrar no `if`

Comment: Primeiro vc encontra o `maiorNumero`, e **depois** faz outro `for` e imprime todas as posições cujo valor é igual ao `maiorNumero`.  Algo como `for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) { if (numero[i] == maiorNumero) { System.out.println("posição " + i); } }` - lembrando que esse é outro `for`, feito depois desse que vc já tem (a diferença é que não precisa guardar a posição, já que vc vai imprimir todas depois)

Comment: Minha nossa! Era muito mais fácil fazer como o @hkotsubo sugeriu.

Comment: perfeito, consegui fazer como a explicação, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se este é um exercício e você só pode usar arrays, uma das formas de se fazer é usando um array auxiliar.

Este array auxiliar será um `boolean[]` e ele servirá para marcar quais índices contém o maior número.

Eu fiz um código comentado para ficar mais clara a minha idéia:

```java
public class App {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] numeros = { 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5 };

    // O array auxilar deve ter o mesmo tamanho do array de números
    boolean[] maiores = new boolean[numeros.length];

    // Consideramos que o maior número é o que está na primeira posição
    int maiorNumero = numeros[0];
    // E por isso marcamos a primeira posição do array auxiliar
    maiores[0] = true;

    for (int i = 1; i < numeros.length; i++) {
      if (numeros[i] > maiorNumero) {
        maiorNumero = numeros[i];

        // Se um novo maior número foi encontrado, temos que zerar o array auxiliar
        for (int j = 0; j < maiores.length; j++) {
          maiores[j] = false;
        }

        // Em seguida marcamos a posição atual
        maiores[i] = true;
      } else if (numeros[i] == maiorNumero) {
        // Se o número atual for iqual ao maior número, apenas marcamos a posição dele
        maiores[i] = true;
      }
    }

    System.out.printf("O maior número é %s e ele está nas posições:\n", maiorNumero);

    for (int i = 0; i < maiores.length; i++) {
      // Depois basta imprimir apenas as posições marcadas
      if (maiores[i]) {
        System.out.println("- " + i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```